# Java: 2D array into 1D array with organisation and random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I want to summarize points each contestant has gotten from each judge (this is stored in a 2D array), I want it to be summarized into 1D array. For example:

> Contestant 1:
>
> Judge 1: 5 points
>
> Judge 2: 3 points
>
> The method should do this: array[0] = 5+3

This is what I created, however it does not work if `judge` is greater than `contestant`, nor do I believe it works properly. I've tried debugging without any further success. allPoints is the 2D array with all the information; for instance, `allPoints[0][0]` is what `judge 1` gave to `contestant 1`.

Any ideas?

```
int output = 0;
        for (int t = 0; t < judge; t++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < contestant; i++) {
                output += allPoints[t][i];
            }
            Sum[t] = output;
            output = 0;
        }
```

Comment: can you share the details how you created the variables, the `allPoints` and `Sum` would be of most interest.

Comment: You probably need Sum[t] to be Sum[i]. I would believe each contestant have a sum linked to him not every judge.

Comment: Your loops are probably mixed up too.

Comment: Show the code which initializes `allPoints`. With the code you showed each row is a judge and each contestant is a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you mixed up in loops. 
If I perfectly guess your problem then solution would be

```
    int output = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<contestant; i++){
        for(int t=0; t<judge; t++){
            output+= allPoints[t][i];  //It has a chance to be  allPoints[i][t] according how  you generate allPoints
        }
        Sum[i] = output;
        output = 0;
    }
```

For every `contestant` calculate total point given by all `judge` and put it to `Sum`. So `Sum` holds total points of each `contestant`.

Comment: Thank you!! I was close to throwing out my computer from the window!

Answer (score 1):

If allPoints[i][j], if i is the judge and j is the contestant. You need to verify this. the proper code would be:

```
int output = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < contestant; j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < judge; i++) {
        output += allPoints[i][j];
    }
    Sum[j] = output;
    output = 0;
}
```

Basically for each contestant you need to sum the points given by each judge. What you are doing now is for each judge you sum the points that he gave to all contestants.